How to make armature also have full range of motion while still connected to master bone?
I'm currently trying to make a short 3D animation with a sentient hammer as the protagonist and I'm stuck at trying to make a good walk cycle for it.
The hammer is all rigged up and I am able to manually make it walk with keyframes, but in trying to make a walk cycle I've run into an issue that I couldn't find a simple solution for.
Here's the rigged up boy for reference:

I have made a "Master Bone" to move the character globally while being able to repeat a walk cycle locally but the issue is that the armature is fixed at where the Master and the first bone connect due to the hierarchy of the bones.
The walk I'm trying to make requires a jump for it to work and having to move the master bone for the walk kinda defeats its purpose in the first place.
The question then is, how do I make it so the skeleton is not limited by the master bone, i.e. doesn't stay stuck in the orange dot, while still being able to use the master to change its global position?

Make it a child of thr master bone or use a child of constraint? Add another mastermaster bone as a parent of the master bone?

I'll try the double master bone and see if it works, but what is a child of constraint?

How to find out. Child of Constraint Doc
